# Can not load GIF from GeoNames link with Glide

Tags: java, android, android-glide

**1 GeoNames**

```
 Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://www.geonames.org/flags/x/ad.gif")
            .into(imageViewFlag_info);
```

**2 Giphy**

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load("https://media.giphy.com/media/98uBZTzlXMhkk/giphy.gif")
        .into(imageViewFlag_info);
```

1 and 2 are different

2nd example works with Giphy but Glide can't load image from GeoNames link.

Comment: You can't load multiple images into the same imageview

Comment: @Zoe Hi, so in my case what way to get the image from geonames.org

Comment: Use another imageview. Assumes you're loading both, that bit is unclear now

Comment: I not loading both it different but with first not working and the second it worked

Answer (score 1):

Specify an appropriate `User-Agent` by using `GlideUrl`:

```
GlideUrl glideUrl = new GlideUrl("https://www.geonames.org/flags/x/ad.gif", new LazyHeaders.Builder()
        .addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
        .build());

Glide.with(this)
        .load(glideUrl)
        .into(imageViewFlag_info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial to setup GlideApp: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-getting-started
Then write this line of code and it should work on your use case

```
GlideApp.with(imageView).asGif().load("URL").into(imageView);
```